# Query USB devices connected to Windows using Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd

There are a lot of answers for C#, C++, python, ubuntu, etc but this is preferred for Windows and python (or else simply call subprocess through python)

I have this code that worked on Ubuntu, but now I want to switch to windows:

```
rpistr = "ls /media/pi > usbs.txt"
p=subprocess.Popen(rpistr,shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
array = []
with open("usbs.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        array.append(line.strip())
```

I'd like to check the ports connected, and list the directory of the USB.

For example, let's say I have `C:\` and `D:\`, but now I plug in a new USB, which will be `F:\` as an example - I want to find out that the path `F:\` is now available to me and be able to copy a file over.

Typical flow:

- Get all Locations
- Pick up that a new location `F:\` is available
- Copy a file over using
  `shutil.copy2`

So how would I identify which port(?) has just been plugged in `F`, `G`, `H`, etc? I plan on running this on an infinite loop, that's why I need to identify when and where the new USB is plugged.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't realize they were called Drives, figured it out and found the right answer.

You can simply use:

```
import win32com.client

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
print(drives)
```

and it will output the answer as such:

```
['C:\\', 'D:\\', 'E:\\', 'F:\\']
```

Just calling on `drives[x]`, `x` being an index, will return the example drive as `X:\` which works perfectly with `shutil`.